# Could I connect a macbook pro to an external hard drive for use with time machine

Tags: mac, hard-drive, time-machine, backup, external-disk

I want to know if connecting a macbook pro to an external hard drive for use with time machine when I am not using it, at night, will work.

If I then disconnect it in the morning (regardless of the progress of the time machine OR journaling) will it cause any problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are third party solutions to **schedule** the timemachine backups. Backing up to any standard USB external harddrive should not be a problem at all.

While I cannot give you a firsthand review, **TimeMachineEditor** seems quite popular and reliable:
https://www.google.fr/search?q=timemachineeditor

When disconnecting the harddrive, you should however always make sure that the backup is finished and no write process is currently done. **Eject** the drive would be the safe thing to do.

Comment: Yah, if you just yank **any** drive out of the port without ejecting it properly Mac OS will scold you. So drag it to the trash/eject or select it and do COMMAND-E to eject it properly.